how to deploy flask api in hostinger vps
root@srv524222:~/barish# python3 app.py

Serving Flask app 'app'
Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
Restarting with stat
Debugger is active!
Debugger PIN: 973-567-398

i already have the flask api file in my vps when im running this url  http://127.0.0.1:5000 browser says page dont exists how to deploy this api?
ive tried many methods but nothing succeed

Flask documentation has several guides on self-hosting. But I'd guess that you still need to read more about self hosting a website.

127.0.0.1 is the local ip address. it always refers to your own computer. So when you type http://127.0.0.1:5000, you are looking for the website on your own computer instead of the server.
You need to type http://your_servers_ip_or_domain_name:5000 to access it from your computer
You may also need to run it on the port 80 instead, or the server's firewall may refuse that connection.
Also, as mentioned on the command line, you are running a development server, unsuitable for a production run on the web. If you are running development, you should probably do that locally. If you are deploying for production, you should use a wsgi as explained in  the flask guide on self-hosting
